# Open file name that is inside the register in Ex mode in Vim

Tags: vim

If I have full path inside a register(e.g. `@a="/dir/file.txt"`) and I want to open the file in Ex mode.

I try `:e @a` that, but it doesn't work.

And I also try `:e echo @a` but it doesn't work either.

Obviously I can type  `:e CTRL-R a` in Ex mode, it works.

But I'm wondering is there a way to get the content of register in Ex mode without use CTRL-R.

Comment: `:execute 'edit' @a`

Comment: FDinoff : please post it as an answer

Answer (score 5):

The `:edit` command takes a file specification. There are certain special characters (like `%` for the current file name; cp. `:h cmdline-special`), but the `@reg` notation does not work here.

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable (or expression); otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument.

So, the solution to your problem is

```
:execute 'edit' @a
```

If you don't want the special characters to apply to the register contents, a more robust (but longer) way is

```
:execute 'edit' fnameescape(@a)
```

Comment: You solve the special character insider the register problem with fnameescape(). Nice!